# Reducing partition prob to decision prob

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, partition, reduction

We have the related and well known problems:

**1) PARTITION (decision problem): 
Given a set S of n natural numbers. Is it possible to find a subset T of S such that the sum of the numbers of T is equal to the sum of the numbers of T\S?**

**2) PARTITION (general problem): 
Given a set S of n natural numbers. Assuming the answer of the decision problem 1) to this set is 'yes' then find such a subset.**

Simple question: How can we solve 2) in polynomial time if we have an algorithm that solves 1) in polynomial time?

Comment: Might be more suitable to ask this on the Computer Science SE.

Comment: You might be right. But i saw similar questions on stackoverflow so i wanted to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Suppose we want to partition a set S of n natural numbers with the sum equal to a number b and we have a blackbox algorithm that solves the decision problem in polynomial time.

`1: If the answer of the partition problem of S is no, then return. 
2: Pick an element x of S. 
3: If x is equal to b/2 return S\x (partition found).
4. Merge x with another element y of S (set x=x+y and set S=S\y) which is not processed yet.
5: Solve the decision problem for S. 
6: If the answer is no then revert step 4, mark y as processed.
7: Go back to step 3.`

Each time we repeat step 2 we have to solve a decision problem in polynomial time. Since we only have to repeat step 2 at most n-1 times, the overall time complexity is also polynomial.